# if statement and group_by function

Tags: r, if-statement, group-by

The code below works perfectly fine for my problem. However, I would like to apply the code if the conditions of ProjectID=="18" | ProjectID=="48" are true.

**Here is my code:**

```
IDD_nhmap <- IDD_nhmap %>%
      group_by(ProjectID) %>%
    bi_class(x = svi,
             y = race_hisp,
             style = "quantile",
             dim = 3) %>%
    mutate() %>%
    rename(bi_class_svi_H = bi_class) %>%
    relocate(svi, race_hisp, bi_class_svi_H, .after = bi_class_ACSB_B)
```

Comment: Can you just filter before i.e. `IDD_nhmap %>% filter(ProjectID %in% c(18, 48)) %>% group_by(ProjectID) %>% ...`. (please consider to provide a small reproducible example) thanks

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Does filtering change the number of rows of the data frame (IDD_nhmap )? I am trying to subset the data without changing the number of rows for the original data frame!

Comment: It does, but you can also do the binding after wards, i.e. `IDD_nhmap %>% filter(ProjectID %in% c(18, 48)) %>% group_by(ProjectID) %>% .... relocate(svi, race_hisp, bi_class_svi_H, .after = bi_class_ACSB_B) %>% bind_rows(IDD_nhmap %>% filter(!(ProjectID %in% c(18, 48))))`.  (As I said, there are some functions in the code (bi_class etc), so not sure without testing

Comment: Please post a few rows of sample input and the corresponding desired output. It's not clear if you want to do this operation only for certain rows, or to the whole data only if certain rows are present, or something else. Sample input and output will help clear up confusion.